# Use of に particle when asking a someone a question

Tags: particle-に

I saw a post online today where a Japanese person wrote the following:

> 彼に何時に行くか聞いてみるね

They also gave an english translation, which more or less matched up with what google translate says

> I'll ask him what time he's going

At first I didn’t understand how this was the transition, but I assume 彼に goes with 聞いてみる. So 彼に○○聞いてみるね becomes “I will try and ask him about X”. Did I understand this correctly?

Also would that mean if the english sentence was something like “I will try and ask Tom what time he’s going to Jim”. Would it be:

> トムさんに何時にジムさんに行くか聞いてみる

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> トムさんに何時に**ジムさんに行く**か聞いてみる

doesn't sound natural because we don't say 「someone + に行く」.

To mean "I'll try asking Tom what time he's going to Jim's (place/home)" you can say

> トムさんに何時にジムさん**のところに**行くか聞いてみる。

---

Likewise,

> **彼に**何時に行くか**聞いてみる**ね。

will be understood as "I'll try asking him what time he's going" since 彼に can continue to 聞いてみる but not to 行く.